# Convert Line Number Into its corresponding co-ordinates

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk

I have a application written in PyGtk. I need to convert a particular line number into its corresponding window co-ordinates in a GtkTextView. How can this be done?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten some details in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by using `gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line()` to get a handle on the line. Then use `gtk_text_view_get_line_yrange()` to convert that into pixel coordinates. Finally use `gtk_text_view_buffer_to_window_coords()` to convert the buffer pixel coordinates into window coordinates.

These are links to the C API calls, but converting to PyGtk should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done, in general.  If you're talking about a line of your pygtk program, then you would need an API for your IDE (development environment) to find out where a particular source code line is currently displayed on the screen, if anywhere.  If by "line number" you mean something else, then as Ignacio says, you'll need to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: Nope that was exactly  wat i wanted to do .. Line Number to text view coordinates conversion. I'm Developing an IDE and i was implementing Code Folding. And i Wanted to place the code folder based on the line numbers

Comment: Ah, I see -- you're *writing* an IDE.  The question sounded like you were using an IDE and writing a pygtk within it, and wanted to know what screen coord a particular source line of the program was.  I think unwind's answer is the right idea.